# Python - print an array as table with column header

Tags: python

I have a python script which produces this output:

```
[(22, 8, 40.0), (23, 1, 5.0), (24, 1, 5.0), ('Friday', 2, 10.0), ('Monday', 4, 20.0), ('Thursday', 2, 10.0), ('Tuesday', 1, 5.0), ('Wednesday', 1, 5.0)]
```

How can I get Python to show me this in a table format with the headings :
`Value, Count, Percentage`

Additionally, I have not managed to get sorting to work. I want it to have the highest percentage value at the top of the list descending order.

My script for the sort was `# sort results sorted(rank_values_perc, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tabulate`:

```py
from tabulate import tabulate

data = [(22, 8, 40.0), (23, 1, 5.0), (24, 1, 5.0), ('Friday', 2, 10.0), ('Monday', 4, 20.0), ('Thursday', 2, 10.0), ('Tuesday', 1, 5.0), ('Wednesday', 1, 5.0)]

header = ['Value', 'Count', 'Percentage']
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
print(tabulate(data, headers=header))
```

You can refer to this link for more options:
[Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)